# How to add items from a list to cells in a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add the items from a list to some rows in an Excel Sheet.
I tried to do it this way:

```
Dim Rand As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Necmontage")
Rand = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Range(ws.Cells(Rand, 1), ws.Cells(Rand + necesar.ListCount - 1, 1)).Merge
ws.Cells(Rand, 1) = "K"

Range(ws.Cells(Rand, 2), ws.Cells(Rand + necesar.ListCount - 1, 2)).Merge
ws.Cells(Rand, 2) = "Montage"

Range(ws.Cells(Rand, 3), ws.Cells(Rand + necesar.ListCount - 1, 3)).Merge
ws.Cells(Rand, 3) = comanda.Caption

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Do While i = necesar.ListCount - 1
    ws.Cells(Rand + i, 4) = necesar.List(i, 0)
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

It adds all the values I want except the values from the List (where I do that While Loop). I don't know why but it doesn't take the values. Any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean in your code:

```
Do While i <= necesar.ListCount - 1 'instead of =
    ws.Cells(Rand + i, 4) = necesar.List(i, 0)
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Btw, you can see in debug mode by putting a breakpoint on the `Do While` line if the program goes where you wanted it to.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot... I changed the While with a For and it worked... I didn't knew what was the problem... Well.. it didn't gave me any error and that's why I didn't use the debug mode.

Comment: Glad it finally worked. Debug mode is useful (especially in vba, you can do step by step and get or set variables values) even if you don't get an error (as soon as you don't get the expected results in fact).